# Synonym request for [mortal-kombat-10] -> [mortal-kombat-x]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I think the official name of the game is Mortal Kombat X, so the [mortal-kombat-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-kombat-10) can be a synonym of [mortal-kombat-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortal-kombat-x). Can someone suggest it?

Comment: Looks like both tags exist at this point too

Comment: Yup. Icebat created a [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/214061/is-mkx-region-locked-on-ps4) with both tags. But I can foresee that more people will use both tags, while just one is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### Merge Results
>
> ```
> updating post history, 4 rows affected (pipe delimited)
> updating posts, 2 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
> updating PostTags associations, 1 rows affected
> removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
> updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
> tag remapping of [mortal-kombat-x] and [mortal-kombat-10] complete!
> remapping 0 synonyms
> 0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
> 0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
> Tag Synonym mortal-kombat-10 -> mortal-kombat-x was approved!
> Broadcasting tag-engine reload
> ```

Comment: Doesn't this go against the [early established policy of using Arabic over Roman numerals](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164/tagging-games-with-numbers-as-series)? In order to comply with precedent, the synonym should actually be the other way around. We do this with the [Final Fantasy games](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2958/mass-roman-arabic-numeral-retag-request), even though their official titles use Roman numerals, so it stands to reason that this should follow suit.

Comment: @FAE I wasn't aware of that convention, sorry. Do you think I should reverse it?

Comment: If we're to stick to the established precedent, I'd say yes, especially given that we still do it for the FF series and Heroes of Might & Magic series, despite their official titles being otherwise. FWIW, a google search of "Mortal Kombat X" vs. "Mortal Kombat 10" resulted in only a 2.9m difference in results (45.2m vs. 43.3m) and google still brought back Mortal Kombat X in its infobox when searching for the latter. I'm unaware of the fine details of how synonyms affect SEO though.